# unityボタン操作について

Tags: unity3d

unityを使ってiPhoneアプリを作っています。
そして、キャラクターをボタンを使って移動やジャンプをさせたいんですが、
２本の指でボタンを挟んでタッチしたところ２本の指の間にあるボタンがタッチしていないのにタッチされたようになってしまいます。
同じく右のボタンと左のボタンを同時にタッチすると真ん中のボタンをタッチした事になってしまいます。
どうすれば良いのか分かりません。アドバイスお願いします。

Comment: Unityのバージョンと、実際のコードを共有できますか? 状況を再現するのに必要な情報をシェアすることで、より役立つ解決策をもらいやすくなります。

Comment: 届いた回答のうちに役にたった回答にチェックマークをつけると質問者と回答者に信頼度がたまります。今後の質問にも役に立ちますよ。

Answer (score 2):

Facebook「Unityユーザー助け合い所」の方には多数コメントが寄せられてます
https://www.facebook.com/groups/unityuserj/permalink/808266705899938/

GUIはマルチタッチに対応してないから、同時タッチに対応したい場合は Input.touches を使いましょう。

Answer (score 0):

こちらを使いましょう。
[スクリプトリファレンス：Touch](http://docs-jp.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Touch.html)

TouchのfingerIdで管理するとやり易いかと思います。